# fiddler - decode custom encrypted body in inspector by c# on the fly

Tags: fiddler

The content is Encrypt with an CUSTOM encrypter. fiddler captured content body is base64 encode string in plain text
[image]

The application traffic flow:

request:

`base64Encode(customEncryptFromStringTobytes(jsonString) ) -> application ->  http server`

response:

`customDecryptFrombytesToString(base64Decode(jsonString) ) <- application <- http server`

I have the encrypt/decrypt class in c#:

`string EncryptToBase64(string plainText);
string DecryptFromBase64(string plainText);`

I build an exe to do the transform, I wonder how To make fiddler decode request/respose body by  this exe on the fly

I want Fiddler show decrypt content in **inspector** , and encrypt again everytime I **[Reissue and Edit(E)]** the request.

I found something close but Dont know how to call an exe to do decode.
http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse

update:
I have implement the custom inspector for Fiddler. see the answer below.

Comment: I would try to implement a [custom inspector](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Extend-Fiddler/CustomInspector) for Fiddler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create an Extension for custom Inspector

full example `https://github.com/chouex/FiddlerExtensionExample`

you will build a dll and copy the file to Inspectors and Scripts folder in fiddler. restart fiddler will load the extenion.

note:
I used pre/post-build script to copy dll and restart fiddler in vs project.

custom inspector:
This Example just beautify the json body.

```
public class ResponseInspector : Inspector2, IResponseInspector2
{
    TextBox myControl;
    private byte[] m_entityBody;
    private bool m_bDirty;

private bool m_bReadOnly;

public bool bReadOnly
{
    get { return m_bReadOnly; }
    set
    {
        m_bReadOnly = value;
        // TODO: You probably also want to turn your visible control CONFIG.colorDisabledEdit (false) or WHITE (true) here depending on the value being passed in.   
    }
}

public void Clear()
{
    m_entityBody = null;
    m_bDirty = false;
    myControl.Text = "";
}

public ResponseInspector()
{
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
}

public HTTPResponseHeaders headers
{
    get { return null; // Return null if your control doesn't allow header editing.
    }
    set { }
}

public byte[] body
{
    get { return m_entityBody; }
    set
    {
        // Here's where the action is.  It's time to update the visible display of the text
        m_entityBody = value;

        if (null != m_entityBody)
        {
            var text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m_entityBody);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && text.StartsWith("{"))
                {
                    text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text), Formatting.Indented);
                }

            myControl.Text = text;
            // TODO: Use correct encoding based on content header.
        }
        else
        {
            myControl.Text = "";
        }

        m_bDirty = false;
        // Note: Be sure to have an OnTextChanged handler for the textbox which sets m_bDirty to true!
    }
}

public bool bDirty
{
    get { return m_bDirty; }
}

public override int GetOrder()
{
    return 0;
}

public override void AddToTab(System.Windows.Forms.TabPage o)
{
    myControl = new TextBox(); // Essentially the TextView class is simply a usercontrol containing a textbox.
    myControl.Height = o.Height;
    myControl.Multiline = true;
    myControl.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
    o.Text = "TextViewExample";
    o.Controls.Add(myControl);
    o.Controls[0].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
}
```

**for Traffic Tamper**(not mention in question but I think this is useful):

implement AutoTamperResponseBefore() in IAutoTamper2

This Example just replace any text from "xt" to "c1" in every request body

Answer (score 0):

Add a dummy header

```
Fiddler-Encoding: base64
```

and encode your body using base64 if it contains any binary data. Fiddler will decode the data before transmitting it to the server.

Taken from http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/composer.asp

Comment: No, I am not asking to decode SSL, The content  is Encrypt with an CUSTOM encrypter. fiddler captured content body is base64 encode string in plain text.

Comment: Altered answer @CharlesChou

Comment: No, I am not transforming data from base64->binrary then send to server. I want the data that SHOWING IN INSPECTOR decode using base64 and then decode by my custom decrypter. Note the server have to receive exactly what client send.

Comment: @Robert know what I need, but I want to do it Simpler.

Comment: I solved by implemented a custom inspector for Fiddler.